# Why doesn't my Intellij Ultimate detect virtualenv?

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-python

I've opened a Python project from IntelliJ Utlimate 2019.2.5 after using Pycharm.

I've the IDEA to a newly created virtualenv project SDK under `<root>/.virtualenv` directory, however, I cannot run `pip install` on the requirements using the terminal because virtualenv is not working, and I'm using my global python installation.

Opening the same project back in Pycharm brings it back to life again.

Is there a specific configuration I've missed (though I doubt that because there are only [these](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-virtual-environment.html) instructions).

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible at the moment in IntelliJ IDEA.
Vote for https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-22067